# Divs side by side which are part of a single form

Tags: html, css, forms

This is my website http://nicholasmills.bhweb.ws/Math%20Quiz/Math%20generator.php and what I want is for the questions to be in a 3 x 3 grid but I don't know how can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap 3 divs which you want side by side in a div having class `.row` Then simply `float: left` the `.Question` divs . Do not forget to clear the float.

**Updated Answer**

```css
body {
  font-family: Iceberg;
}
#Header {
  text-align: center;
}
#Quiz {
  /*  width: 200px; Remove this */
  margin-left: 10%;
}
.Question {
  border-style: solid;
  margin: 10px 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height:100px;
  float: left
}
#UserDataBox {
  display: none;
}
.row {
  max-width: 680px;
}
.clearfix {
  clear: both
}
```

```html
<h1 id="Header">Math Quiz</h1>
<br>
<br>

<div id="Quiz">
  <form id="QuizQuestions" action="SaveMathData.php" method="post">

    <div class='row'>
      <div class="Question">
        Date:
        <input type="text" name="FormDate" value="00 00 0000" />
        <br>Your username:
        <input type="text" name="CurrentUser" value="No-one" />
      </div>

      <div class="Question" id="ClassSelect">
        <p>What class are you in?</p>
        <select name="class" required="required">
          <option disabled selected>Select a class</option>
          <option value="Class1">Class 1</option>
          <option value="Class2">Class 2</option>
          <option value="Class3">Class 3</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="Question">
        <p id="Question1"></p>
        Question 1 Answer?
        <input class="QuestionBox" id="Question1Box" type="text" name="Question1UserAnswer" />
        <p class="AnswerBox" id="Question1AnswerBox"></p>
        <img src="" />

      </div>
      <div class='clearfix'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class="Question">
        <p id="Question2"></p>
        Question 2 Answer?
        <input class="QuestionBox" id="Question2Box" type="text" name="Question2UserAnswer" />
        <br>
        <p class="AnswerBox" id="Question2AnswerBox"></p>
        <br>
        <br>
      </div>



      <div class="Question">
        <p id="Question3"></p>
        Question 3 Answer?
        <input class="QuestionBox" id="Question3Box" type="text" name="Question3UserAnswer" />
        <br>
        <p class="AnswerBox" id="Question3AnswerBox"></p>
        <br>
        <br>
      </div>



      <div class="Question">
        <p id="Question4"></p>
        Question 4 Answer?
        <input class="QuestionBox" id="Question4Box" type="text" name="Question4UserAnswer" />
        <br>
        <p class="AnswerBox" id="Question4AnswerBox"></p>
        <br>
        <br>
      </div>
      <div class='clearfix'></div>
    </div>

    <div class='row'>
      <div class="Question">
        <p id="Question5"></p>
        Question 5 Answer?
        <input class="QuestionBox" id="Question5Box" type="text" name="Question5UserAnswer" />
        <br>
        <p class="AnswerBox" id="Question5AnswerBox"></p>
        <br>
        <br>
      </div>



      <div class="Question">
        <p id="Question6"></p>
        Question 6 Answer?
        <input class="QuestionBox" id="Question6Box" type="text" name="Question6UserAnswer" />
        <br>
        <p class="AnswerBox" id="Question6AnswerBox"></p>
        <br>
        <br>
      </div>



      <div class="Question">
        <p id="Question7"></p>
        Question 7 Answer?
        <input class="QuestionBox" id="Question7Box" type="text" name="Question7UserAnswer" />
        <br>
        <p class="AnswerBox" id="Question7AnswerBox"></p>
        <br>
        <br>
      </div>
      <div class='clearfix'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='row'>

      <div class="Question">
        <p id="Question8"></p>
        Question 8 Answer?
        <input class="QuestionBox" id="Question8Box" type="text" name="Question8UserAnswer" />
        <br>
        <p class="AnswerBox" id="Question8AnswerBox"></p>
        <br>
        <br>
      </div>



      <div class="Question">
        <p id="Question9"></p>
        Question 9 Answer?
        <input class="QuestionBox" id="Question9Box" type="text" name="Question9UserAnswer" />
        <br>
        <p class="AnswerBox" id="Question9AnswerBox"></p>
        <br>
        <br>
      </div>



      <div class="Question">
        <p id="Question10"></p>
        Question 10 Answer?
        <input class="QuestionBox" id="Question10Box" type="text" name="Question10UserAnswer" />
        <br>
        <br>
        <p class="AnswerBox" id="Question10AnswerBox"></p>
        <br>
        <br>
      </div>
      <div class='clearfix'></div>
    </div>









    <input style="display:none;" id="SubmitButton" type="submit" value="Submit Answers" />
  </form>

  <button id="CheckButton" onclick="CheckAnswers()">Check Answers</button>
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: I just tried that but it didn't work I have left the website up with the code you said but now it looks a bit weird. Did i do something wrong?

Comment: As said above, remove ` 200px` from `#Quiz {width: 200px;margin-left:10%;}` . Check updated answer as well. Do come back if any issue.!

Comment: Just tried the edited version and now it looks well different.

Comment: Since you are having trouble applying the code. Please check the working code above

Comment: Also check this fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/ggz6y9ka/

Comment: I think i see the miss understanding you have solved my problem but if forgot to say that is still wanted the boxes the same size not like this http://nicholasmills.bhweb.ws/Math%20Quiz/Math%20generator2.php

Comment: Ok. Then check the update answer. Customize the size of boxes as per your need  and the jsfiddle link - https://jsfiddle.net/ggz6y9ka/1/ . Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: Just so I don't break this code if per-say someone wanted to all of the boxes in another div would the code still work?

Comment: The layout is completely controllable. You may have to update a bit of code in case you decide to change the layout in future.

Answer (score 0):

```
.Question {
   width: 30%;
   float: left;
   height: 6em;
}
```